# How does ceiling (rnorm) works?

Tags: r, ceil

I am new to R.

At the moment I am learning the ceiling codes as followed:
`df4 <- data.frame(Y=rnorm(5),Z=ceiling(rnorm(5)))`

My question is, what does the ceiling do in this case.

The result for the code above is like below:

```
       Y      Z
1 -0.5237500  0
2 -1.2548762 -1
3  0.9723432  0
4  0.1974542  1
5  1.3507062  1
```

(It bothers me since this doesn't look like usual ceiling function to me.)

Any help or/and explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: `rnorm(5)` generates 5 random values from a normal distribution where mean = 0 and sd = 1 and `ceiling` rounds the value up to the nearest integer

Comment: @Relasta No it does not, it rounds to the closest integer **not less** than its argument.

Comment: You are taking the `ceiling` of different numbers. The call to `rnorm` that gets the `Y` values is not the same as for the `Z` values.

Comment: @RuiBarradas How is rounding the value up to the nearest integer different to rounding to the closest integer not less than the value?

Comment: @Relasta 0 is closest to 0.4 but the ceiling is 1. (Actually when rounding it's to the closest *even* integer.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas which is why I said it rounds the value **up** to the nearest integer.

Comment: @Relasta OK, if that's what you meant, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Ceiling doesn't produce the expected results here because the vector produced in `Y` is different from the one produced in `Z` - in each of them you are sampling a new set of numbers.

What you should do is this:

```
library(dplyr)
df4 <- data.frame(Y=rnorm(5))
df4 <- df4 %>% mutate(Z = ceiling(Y))
```

Comment: `ceiling` doesn't work incorrectly of course. You should phrase as something like "the `Z` column might have values you don't expect because..".

Comment: Maybe it's better if you call `set.seed` prior to calling `rnorm`. Upvote, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any package, first create `dataframe` of random number and invoke the `ceiling`:

```
df4 <- data.frame(Y=rnorm(5))
df4$Z <-ceiling(df4$Y)
df4
          Y   Z
1  0.3466323  1
2 -0.3913280  0
3 -1.8246212 -1
4 -0.1052592  0
5 -1.4643682 -1
```

Comment: Maybe it's better if you call `set.seed` prior to calling `rnorm`. Upvote, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `Z=ceiling(rnorm(5))` here refer to the ceiling of Z value / Z score that generated randomly. It totally independent with Y variable. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

the ceiling function always rounds to the larger number, that means negatives get rounded in direction of the zero.

In your code you are generating two different set of numbers, because the pseudo random number generator doesn't recycle old values for the `rnorm()` function:

**testcode:**

```
set.seed(42)    
df <- data.frame(Y=rnorm(5),Z=rnorm(5))
```

**output**

```
   Y           Z  
1  1.3709584 -0.10612452  
2 -0.5646982  1.51152200  
3  0.3631284 -0.09465904  
4  0.6328626  2.01842371  
5  0.4042683 -0.06271410
```

so the ceiling

```
df4$Z <- ceiling(df4$Z)
```

creates the output

```
   Y         Z
1  1.3709584 0
2 -0.5646982 2
3  0.3631284 0
4  0.6328626 3
5  0.4042683 0
```

if you want to get the ceiling of Y use:

```
df4 <- data.frame(Y=rnorm(5))
df4$Z <- ceiling(df4$Y)
```